# Bias-Variance Tradeoff Derivation

Tags: random-variables, machine-learning

I was looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Derivation) derivation of the bias-variance tradeoff. In the last block of the derivation it is claimed that

$\text{E}[f\hat{f}] + \text{E}[\varepsilon\hat{f}] = \text{E}[f\hat{f}] + \text{E}[\varepsilon]\text{E}[\hat{f}]$

since $\hat{f}$ and $\varepsilon$ are independent. Can someone explain why they are independent? This question has been asked [before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340553/bias-variance-decomposition-derivation-question-proof-from-wikipedia?newreg=2a0f2d5b2d4846b88d78b1284b5c7efa), and as one comment points out, it doesn't make a lot of sense intuitively:

> Intuitively, $\varepsilon$ is the irreducible error due to e.g. measurement errors, which is independent from the model estimates $\hat{f}$. However, in practice, the level of noise in training data determines the data quality, which in turn impose huge impact on getting $\hat{f}$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $\hat f$ is determined by the data $D$ so you may think that $\hat f$ depends on $\epsilon$. It is partially right but not exactly write. Yes $\hat f$ depends on the noise involved in the training data. But $\epsilon$ here can be regarded as noise involved with a new data. That means $\epsilon$ here is independent of the training data $D$. Thus $\hat f$ is independent from $\epsilon$.

Comment: That helps, thanks a lot!